# Firebase write to parent node but prevent writing direct to child nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a use case in which I need a user to provide a set of data to a certain location in Firebase, but not the ability to alter individual child nodes of that location at a time.

As an example, let's say that I have a user that has the ability to write to a tree, `requests`, that a different system is watching so that it can process the requests. Also, rather than using `.push()` to generate a Firebase pushID to uniquely identify the request, we just have a singular location where requests are written to. The structure could look like the following:

```
requests: {
  UserID1: {
    requestParam1: "Some parameter",
    requestParam2: "Another parameter"
  }
}
```

To be clear, the system that is processing requests would be listening to `requests/UserID1` so that it gets notified of any change to the structure and processes the request.

Let's also say that both `requestParam1` and `requestParam2` are always required. The reason for requiring these parameters for each write to the `UserID1` node is to prevent a user from *only* writing to `requestParam1` and then the system that is processing requests doesn't get a request that essentially receives a *new* `requestParam1` and an *old* `requestParam2`.

It's simple to ensure that, when writing to `UserID1`, both parameters are included, but I can't figure out how to stop writes to the child nodes directly.

Here are my rules thus far:

```
"requests": {
  "$userID": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && newData.exists()",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['requestParam1', 'requestParam2'])"
    "requestParam1": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    },
    "requestParam2": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString()"
    }
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

If I attempt to write to `UserID1` without one of the request parameters, it rejects the write -- this is correct. However, when I write directly to `UserID1/requestParam1`, the attempt is successful, which is not the desired behavior.

I've included `".write": false` rules in both of the `requestParam`'s, but the write is still allowed. I believe this is because the write is deemed allowable by the write rule in the parent node, and therefore cascades to the child node. Based on the documentation, I don't think there is a way to get around that one. However, I thought I'd get clever and make each of the child nodes check the child contents of `newData.parent()` as follows:

```
"requests": {
  "$userID": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && newData.exists()",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['requestParam1', 'requestParam2'])"
    "requestParam1": {
      ".validate": "
        newData.parent().exists() &&
        newData.parent().hasChildren(['requestParam1', 'requestParam2']) &&
        newData.isString()
      "
    },
    "requestParam2": {
      ".validate": "
        newData.parent().exists() &&
        newData.parent().hasChildren(['requestParam1', 'requestParam2']) &&
        newData.isString()
      "
    }
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

I wasn't sure about adding the `newData.parent().exists()` check so I threw it in there for good measure, but I thought that the `newData().parent().hasChildren([...])` rules would make this all work, but I was wrong. Writes to the individual children are still allowed.

Ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I also attempted moving the `newData.hasChildren([...])` rule that was previously in the `.validate` section into the `.write` section in the `$userID` rules, but no luck.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. `newData` contains the merged result, so you can't enforce rules on just the updated data.

Comment: @AnidMonsur, what do you mean that "`newData` contains the merged result"? I would think that `newData` contains the data that is *about* to be written to the location, so that it could be checked by a `.validate` rule before actually being written to that location.

Comment: From the docs: [it is a "merging" of the existing data plus the new data being written](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/newdata.html)

Comment: @AnidMonsur, thanks for pointing that out - the name `newData` is now more confusing than I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @AnidMonsur, `newData` "is a 'merging' of the existing data plus the new data being written" ([from the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/newdata.html)), so it is not really *just* the new data, which definitely makes the question harder to answer.

One potential way to accomplish this would be to ensure that the newData that will be written to each location will be different from the data that is already at that location (if it exists). But, in the event that it is the intention of the user to write the same data into the field, this isn't a viable solution.

However, I think I have an alternative that may work. For each piece of data, i.e. `requestParam1` and `requestParam2`, the rules should enforce that the *priority* of the rule is equivalent to [now](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/now.html) and ensuring that the priorities of the data match. This would enforce the client making the request to include the priority in each request for each piece of data. This results in the following rules:

```
"requests": {
  "$userID": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && newData.exists()",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['requestParam1', 'requestParam2'])"
    "requestParam1": {
      ".validate": "
        newData.isString() &&
        newData.getPriority() !== null &&
        newData.getPriority() === now &&
        newData.parent().child('requestParam2').getPriority() === newData.getPriority()
      "
    },
    "requestParam2": {
      ".validate": "
        newData.isString() &&
        newData.getPriority() !== null &&
        newData.getPriority() === now &&
        newData.parent().child('requestParam1').getPriority() === newData.getPriority()
      "
    }
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to subvert this strategy... I guess it is *possible* for two users to write to the two locations at the exact same time, but I'm not sure how to avoid that (plus, it seems very unlikely).

Also, as a side note, if anyone wanted to know how to include a priority in your data if it is just a string/number/boolean type, you can structure the data in the write as follows:

```
//before:
var data = "Some data"

/after:
var data = {
  ".value": "Some data",
  ".priority": Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```